# Cart and Cart Item relations in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
models.py

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="cart")
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='product')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

```
serializers.py

class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['user','status']


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cart = CartSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['cart', 'product', 'quantity']
```

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/', AddItem.as_view(),name='add'),
]
```

```
views.py

class AddItem(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

How can I connect the "cart" in Item without asking it directly in Django Rest Framework? I'm sending {"product":1,"quantity":1}, however it asks for "cart" to be sent. I can't figure out how to make DRF automatically resolve it as it's connected to the cart.

Comment: How do you keep track of the cart between requests?

Answer (score 1):

Because you used ModelSerializer and define cart in fields list inside ItemSerializer. Serializer validate methods checks your data based on your model. You can find details [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm really struggling to understand it.

Comment: Okey, I will try to give more detail. Django serializer classes have validate method in default. You can override it for add custom validation. It compares your data and your model class. For example if you have a IntegerField in your model and you send a string for this field, it raise validation error. Like that if you have not nullable field in your model and you don't send any data for this field, it raise exception again. It is very simple actually.